# Why HTML form tag provide only 2 methods

Tags: html, http

Why does the HTML `<form>` tag provide only the two methods GET and POST? THe HTTP specifications has other verbs as well like PUT, DELETE, etc.

Comment: perhaps you should ask that the guy that has written the html specs

Comment: Actually the support for other methods was officially removed in HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-diff-20101019/#changes-2010-06-24 "Using PUT and DELETE as HTTP methods for the form element is no longer supported. "

Comment: @ThiefMaster — The support was only added in an earlier version of the HTML 5 draft. It has never been standard.

Comment: But I think Before HTML5 also form tag did not allowed o populate PUT , OPTIONS, HEAD ..etc as method attribute value

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Comment: It's an open issue with HTML5. See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/tracker/issues/195, http://www.w3.org/wiki/User:Cjones/ISSUE-195 and  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/User:Eoconnor/ISSUE-195

Answer (score 1):

None of the other methods are expected to include data organised in a way that HTML forms are designed to provide.

For example, DELETE would be expected to delete whatever resource the action attribute pointed to. Including form data in such a request would be entirely meaningless.

Comment: What about PUT its specification says that it can create as well as update the resource. So, why that is not supported...?

Comment: A form is designed to collect input from the user. "I want to delete the URI the form points to" doesn't collect much in the way of input (and isn't something many people would want). PUT will create or overwrite a URI with whatever it is uploaded with. I can't think of a single usecase for uploading x-form-urlencoded documents so that they are available for download.

Comment: A form tag can even GET resource.. on a click..... User does not need to provide any input. Just a click event. thats it

Comment: So? There is a clearly specified way to collect user data and submit it in a GET request (i.e. the query string). Search engines make extensive use of it to collect search terms from users and provide them with pages of results (which are bookmarkable).

Comment: but that's not necessary I append query string each time I make a GET request.

Comment: I can create a form tag with GET method just to change the page & that can be defined by action attribute.Right??

Comment: You can also use tables for layout. That doesn't mean what you are doing is sane or that you are using HTML as it is designed to be used.

Comment: Using Tables for Layout is Sane.. Whats wrong in that as far as it is in contract with HTTP specifications...

Comment: [Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content … authors should use style sheets to control layout rather than tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1).

Comment: So???? they are saying you can use Tables for layout but Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media.......

TableLayout is an alternative to GridBagLayout and if suits ones application. Whats wrong in using that.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Applying CSS to make non-table elements use the algorithms for layout that tables use by default is not the same as using tables for layout (and [W3Schools is a dreadful resource](http://w3fools.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

HTML did always only allow GET and POST as methods for forms. The reason for that is probably because both [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6) and [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.7) are meant to affect the resource identified by the URI instead of referring to the resource that just processes the request:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is
> reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a
> POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed
> entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to
> some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations.
> In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed
> with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the
> server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.
>
> […]
>
> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource
> identified by the Request-URI. This method MAY be overridden by human
> intervention (or other means) on the origin server.

This would also require the web server itself to handle the requests appropriately, handling other aspects like authentication and authorization as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because back in the day, no popular browsers ever implemented anything beyond POST and GET.

By now, it seems to be too much hassle to get browser makers together to standardize how DELETE, PUT, PATCH, etc. would work with forms. Even if we could get browser makers in agreement, it would most likely be at least a decade before enough users had upgraded to new enough browsers for the feature to become mainstream.

Note that there are ways to work around this on an application-by-application basis. Ruby on Rails provides a `:method` option to its [`form_tag` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) that allows for submitting more methods by simply using a POST with a special parameter.

Comment: JavaScript (or rather the XMLHttpRequest object) allows custom crafted HTTP requests to be submitted. They can have dynamically selected URIs, arbitrary request headers and whatever message body you like. There is a world of difference between that and submitting a collection of form data.

Comment: Right, and there is no standardized way to use Javascript to parse the DOM to figure out the form contents and then send that up via AJAX. You just have to follow a convention, which would usually just be doing the same thing POST would have done.